# How test if a void pointer is a struct or string?

Tags: objective-c

Can I test the type of a void pointer? I want to solve this problem:

```
void log(void *test) {
    if (is a struct) {
        NSLog(test);
    } else {
        printf("%s\n", test);
    }    
}

log(@"This send a struct (NSString)");
log("This send normal string");
```

There are a easy way to test it?

Comment: Those tags make this question completely ambiguous.

Comment: Why did you tag these with 3 different languages? Each language has a different way to accomplish this. Also why would you want to write your Log method like that? Instead declare two different log() methods each with a different input type (NSString) and (char*)

Comment: objective-c is a superset of c. But you can use c++ in Objective-c++.. Maybe the c++ isn't a good choice.

Comment: A `void*` is applicable in all 3 languages. I see nothing wrong with the tagging.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718412/find-out-type-of-c-void-pointer

Comment: @Rodrigo, who taught you it? Those are three different languages. Period. TheBuzzSaw - but people tend to mark all of c/c++/obj-c questions with all of the tags (or use just both c and c++ tag - seen question where it was reasonable only once). Obj-c and c++ are based on C, but _C is not their subset!_

Comment: Well all three of them have a void* and within all three of them it has the same meaning. Objective-C's **id** is a different thing.

Comment: No, and you can't work out how long an array is from a pointer to its element either, just in case you want to know that too.....

Comment: Duplicate of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144629/in-objective-c-how-do-i-test-the-object-type

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw: What is the single solution that works across all three languages?

Comment: Sorry to jump all over you, @Rodrigo. I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but what you are doing is actually wrought with danger. One of the big jumps from C to C++ and Objective-C was adding in type safety, which when used properly cuts down on some major issues. By using void* as a "generic any" type, you are circumventing typesafety. Sometimes it's a necessarily evil to accomplish a task, but in your example, having a generic logging method doesn't appear to be one of those times.

Answer (score 6):

No you cannot test this. A void* is just a memory address where anything (or even nothing) could be stored. It's meaning is entirely implementation dependent and only the original programmer (or the documentation) knows.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no way to do that kind of detection in a non implementation specific way since when you cast the NSString to a void* you throw away all typing information and convert it to an "untyped pointer to memory".

I'm not sure why you want this kind of functionality, but if it's between two objects, you should use "id" instead of void* since that preserves all type information.

In this specific example, it would probably make a lot more sense to just make "log" an overloaded function and thereby know the type of the parameter compile time.

Comment: If you have a pointer to an _object_, it's possible to find out its class by messaging it (`-class`, `-isKindOfClass:`, `-isMemberOfClass:`) regardless of the type of the pointer itself. One is runtime information, the other is compile-time.

Comment: @JoshCaswell True, but if you're sure they're all objects, I can't see the reason to cast to a type "lower" than id. When you cast to void* you're more or less deliberately discarding the information that you're dealing with an object.

Comment: You're right, there's few reasons to do it, and your second paragraph is generally good advice but, for example, I was monkeying around with `NSInvocation` and libffi recently, both of which require objects to be moved around via `void *` occasionally. Other C-style interfaces might require the same.