# How to specify parameter packs that accept any type or value?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

When specifying the parameter packs for a type, I want to be able to accept not only `typename`s but also values of arbitrary types. Example:

```
template <thing... Things>
//        ^^^^^   <- pseudo code
struct Example {};

Example<int,bool>();
Example<4,float,'x'>();
```

Clearly, `thing` is not a valid C++ keyword, but is the idea expressed here at all possible?

---

The context for this is that I have a container adapter that wants to insert its own value type into the container but allow to pass any additional template parameters, and some containers receive not just type arguments but also values (`std::array` would be a popular example).

```
template <template <typename...> typename Container, typename... Args>
struct Adapter {
  struct Node { /* ... */ };
  Container<Node,Args...> container;
};

Adapter<std::vector>(); // fine
Adapter<std::vector,MyAllocator>(); // fine
Adapter<std::array,3>(); // nope because 3 is not a typename
```

Comment: Not possible, at the moment (C++17 but also C++20, as far I know). The best I can suggest is wrap values inside a class (by example: not `3` but `std::integral_constant<int, 3>`).

Comment: @max66 Yes, my thinking was also going to something like `integral_constant`, but that would require the underlying types to accept this, which (for example) `std::array` does not. And there couldn't even be an overload for the same reason.

Comment: Assuming you know the possible values passed, can't you just use a `void *` and then try reading it as all possible values to find valid ones?
Otherwise try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718412/find-out-type-of-c-void-pointer)