# sfinae to detect containers: failure for std:array

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, sfinae, stdarray

I am looking for a way to use SFINAE to implement some function, that must be available only to some containers:
vector, list, array (set is there below only as a test)

Build upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12045843/193789), I tried the code below that uses a traits class that returns true only for the required containers.

As you can see [online here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25426c0a8d68a90f), it fails for `std::array`.

```
template <typename Container>
struct is_container : std::false_type { };

template <typename... Ts> struct is_container<std::array<Ts... >> : std::true_type { };
template <typename... Ts> struct is_container<std::vector<Ts...>> : std::true_type { };
template <typename... Ts> struct is_container<std::set<Ts...   >> : std::true_type { };
template <typename... Ts> struct is_container<std::list<Ts...  >> : std::true_type { };
template <typename... Ts> struct Dummy{};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Dummy: " << is_container<Dummy<int>>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "array: " << is_container<std::array<int,5>>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "vector:" << is_container<std::vector<int>>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "set: "   << is_container<std::set<int>>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "list: "  << is_container<std::list<int>>::value << '\n';
}
```

What I understand is that this is due to the fact that `std::array` requires a second template parameter.
I have a low experience with variadic templates, so my question is:

**Is there a way to make this approach successful?**
Or shall I use another approach described in the linked question?

I'd rather have something pure C++11, but C++14 would be ok too.

Comment: The problem is that second template parameter is not a type but a number. Thus the specialisation doesn't fit.

Comment: i was about to add the `c++11` tag but it was interleaved with another edit that added already the max 5 tags. Imho it would be nice to have the `c++11` tag but didnt want to decide what else to remove

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not SFINAE but regular template specialisation. Your std::array is not recognised because a value of type std::size_t (which ist std::array's second argument) [is not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63511221/430766) a typename.

You can change your check for array specifically:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N> struct is_container<std::array<T,N>> : std::true_type { };
template <typename... Ts> struct is_container<std::vector<Ts...>> : std::true_type { };
```

If you actually want to use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to check for anything that behaves like a container, you could check for the existance of std::begin, std::end, std::size for that type.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, I meant this will be used in some Sfinae template function.

Comment: @kebs I see. Well you could actually allow for a more generic test if you check for properties of a container than listing the container explicitly. What if your user decides to use a `std::unordered_set` rather than a `std::set` or a `std::deque` instead of a `std::list`. Or a custom container, or ...

Comment: The point is to allow the function code only the 3 listed constainers. For std::set, the idea is to let the build fail.

Comment: Ah. In that case you may want to change the set line to `template <typename... Ts> struct is_container<std::set<Ts...   >> : std::false_type { };` or just completely remove that line because you have a default that goes to false_type.

Comment: Sure, yes. It was there just as a test. Or better, I'll just remove that line.

Comment: Does this answer you question, then?

Comment: Yep, the two answers are basically the same, usually when that happen, I accept the one from the lowest rep ;-) Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the 2nd template parameter of `std::array` is a non-type template parameter, which doesn't match type template parameter pack `typename... Ts`.

You can change the specialization for `std::array` to:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t S> struct is_container<std::array<T, S>> : std::true_type { };
```