# Passing variadic template arguments to another template

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have this code in which `static_for` can be used as a compile-time loop using template-metaprogramming and `loop_types` is a `struct` accepting variadic arguments.
Whenever I try to call the function `call`, it give me an error.

In `loop_types`, the is a template `loop` contain the function that prints name of the types.

```cpp
//Template specialization for getting an index of variadic template
template <unsigned long long index, typename... P>
struct variadic_type_template_index;

template <typename T,typename... P>
struct variadic_type_template_index<0,T,P...>
{
    using type = T;
};

template <unsigned long long index,typename T,typename... P>
struct variadic_type_template_index<index,T,P...>
{
    using type = variadic_type_template_index<index-1,P...>::type;
};

template <unsigned long long index,typename... T>
using variadic_type_template_index_t = variadic_type_template_index<index,T...>::type;




//Rest of the program

#include <stdlib.h> // For malloc
#include <iostream> // For std::cout

template <template <unsigned long long,unsigned long long> typename tocall,unsigned long long initval,unsigned long long times>
struct static_for;


template <template <unsigned long long,unsigned long long> typename tocall,unsigned long long initval,unsigned long long times>
requires requires(){tocall<initval,times>::toCall();}
struct static_for<tocall,initval,times>
{
    static_assert(initval<times,"Invalid static_for loop");
    constexpr static void call()
    {
        tocall<initval,times>::toCall();
        static_for<tocall,initval +1,times>::call();
    }
};
template <template <unsigned long long,unsigned long long> typename tocall,unsigned long long val>
struct static_for<tocall,val,val>
{
    constexpr static void call()
    {}
};

template <typename... Args>
struct loop_types
{
    template <unsigned long long i,unsigned long long t>
    struct loop
    {
        using type = variadic_type_template_index_t<i,Args...>;
        static void toCall()
        {
            std::cout<<typeid(type).name()<<"\n";
        }
    };
};

template <typename... Args>
void call(Args...)
{
    static_for<loop_types<Args...>::loop,0,sizeof...(Args)>::call();
}


int main()
{
    call("1",2,true,malloc(5));
}
```

### Error message I get

```
ToRun.cpp: In function 'void call(Args ...)':
ToRun.cpp:67:59: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<long long unsigned int <anonymous>, long long unsigned int <anonymous> > class tocall, long long unsigned int initval, long long unsigned int times> struct static_for'
   67 |     static_for<loop_types<Args...>::loop,0,sizeof...(Args)>::call();
      |                                                           ^
ToRun.cpp:67:59: note:   expected a class template, got 'loop_types<Args ...>::loop'
ToRun.cpp:67:66: warning: empty parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
   67 |     static_for<loop_types<Args...>::loop,0,sizeof...(Args)>::call();
      |                                                                  ^~
ToRun.cpp:67:66: note: remove parentheses to default-initialize a variable
   67 |     static_for<loop_types<Args...>::loop,0,sizeof...(Args)>::call();
      |                                                                  ^~
      |                                                                  --
ToRun.cpp:67:66: note: or replace parentheses with braces to value-initialize a variable
```

How can I fix this problem?

Also, in case I replace `Args...` with a number of types ifself like with `int,char,bool` along with specifying number of types itself, the code works properly.

Compiler used - GCC

Command used

```
g++ ToRun.cpp -o ToRun -std=c++23 && "ToRun.exe"
```

I was expecting the program to print the types' name of every parameter  I passes to `call`

Comment: In `loop_types<Args...>::loop` the compiler cannot tell if `loop` is supposed to be a type or a value. You can help it by adding a `typename` just before it, `typename loop_types<Args...>::loop`.

Comment: ^That. Type/value mismatch means the compiler is expecting a type/value but is getting the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate or related:  [How to specify parameter packs that accept any type or value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63511221/430766)

Comment: @bitmask Both are different questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `call()` function... passing through a `using` should solve the problem

```
template <typename... Args>
void call(Args...)
{
  using for_t = static_for<loop_types<Args...>::template loop, 0, sizeof...(Args)>;

  for_t::call();
}
```

but remember to add a couple of `typename` in `variadic_type_template_index` specialization and `using`

```
template <unsigned long long index,typename T,typename... P>
struct variadic_type_template_index<index,T,P...>
{
    using type = typename variadic_type_template_index<index-1,P...>::type;
    // ..........^^^^^^^^
};

template <unsigned long long index,typename... T>
using variadic_type_template_index_t = typename variadic_type_template_index<index,T...>::type;
// ....................................^^^^^^^^
```

and also a dummy `variadic_type_template_index<0>` specialization, by example

```
template <>
struct variadic_type_template_index<0>
{
    using type = void;
};
```

or you get a compilation error from

```
requires requires(){tocall<initval,times>::toCall();}
```

when `initval` is equal to `times`

Comment: The code still worked without ```typename```s